# Handsontable sort data from backend database over json/ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, sorting, handsontable

I want to make use of the Handsontable column sorting and direction indicators to send a sort request to my DB and display the corresponding results.

The Handsontable sort plugin works nicely (allows clicking on a column header) but only sorts the currently loaded data, as per their [docs](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.11.0/demo-sorting.html)

```
var hot = new Handsontable(document.getElementById('example'), {
  columnSorting: true
});
```

How can I trigger my own method when the user clicks on a column header?

I understand I can use jQuery to catch the click and work out the column and direction and trigger my own method but this seems clumsy if it's already being listened to and tracked by Handsontable.

I'd prefer to overwrite the method or hook into the table somehow so Handsontable keeps track of the state of the sorting (column and direction) and I use that information to fetch data from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

From this [git](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2819) issue I found the [beforeColumnSort](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.11.0/Hooks.html#event:beforeColumnSort) hook

```
var hot = new Handsontable(document.getElementById('example'), {
  columnSorting: true,
  beforeColumnSort: function(column, order){
    // reload sorted data from server here
  }
});
```